# Calculate the molarity of Na+ ions in 20 mL of a .130 M solution of Na2Cr2O7?

Tags: aqueous-solution, ions, stoichiometry

The answer is $\pu{0.260 M}$, but I keep getting $\pu{0.0052 M}$ because I thought the right way to do it was by multiplying $\pu{0.130 M}$ by $\pu{0.02 L}$, then multiplying by $2$ moles of $\ce{Na+}$. What would be the right way?

Answer (score 1):

$0.0052$ is the number of moles of $\ce{Na+}$ ions in solution, but to find the molarity, you need to divide by $\pu{0.02 L}$. Therefore, the final answer is $\ce{2\cdot 0.130 \cdot 0.02 \cdot \frac{1}{0.02} = 0.260 M}$